# Show tag descriptions when asking a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, mobile-web

I am a user of [English Language SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/), but I think this question might apply throughout the site.

Often new users (but not always new users) will add tags which aren't really relevant to the question. This is probably because they add in all the lingustic terms they can think of, in the hopes that one will stick.

It might help if a user can see descriptions of the tags when they add them, so they can see what the tag really is about.

I'm not sure if this already happens on the desktop since I use the mobile site, so this might already be a feature. If so, would it be advantageous to add it to mobile too?

Comment: Tag descriptions *are* shown on the main site, provided you're using a desktop computer, or you've disabled responsiveness. (If the main site is loaded responsively on a mobile device, they will once again be hidden.)

Comment: @Sonic Good to know. I guess most new users aren't using the mobile version, so it's up to the tag descriptions.